# Using stock markets in Europe, how can I buy commodities / resources, to diversify my portfolio?

Tags: stocks, portfolio, commodities, european-union, diversification

I am in Europe and I would like to differentiate my portfolio in buying resources, such as oil, sulphuric acid, titanium etc. Of course not in material form, but as stocks. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend *avoiding* trading directly in commodities futures and options.  If you're not prepared to learn a lot about how futures markets and trading works, it will be an experience fraught with pitfalls and lost money – and I am speaking from experience.

Looking at stock-exchange listed products is a reasonable approach for an individual investor desiring added diversification for their portfolio.  Still, **exercise caution** and **know what you're buying.**

It's easy to access many commodity-based exchange-traded funds (ETFs) on North American stock exchanges.  If you already have low-cost access to U.S. markets, consider this option – but be mindful of currency conversion costs, etc.

Yet, **there is also a European-based company, [ETF Securities](http://www.etfsecurities.com)**, headquartered in Jersey, Channel Islands, which offers many exchange-traded funds on European exchanges such as London and Frankfurt.  ETF Securities started in 2003 by first offering a gold commodity exchange-traded fund.

- Funds that trade on the London Stock Exchange: [Commodity ETC List](http://www.etfsecurities.com/en/securities/etfs_securities.asp).
- Funds that trade on Börse Frankfurt: [ETC - Liste](http://www.etfsecurities.com/de/securities/etfs_securities.asp).

I also found the following: [London Stock Exchange: Frequently Asked Questions about ETCs](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/traders-and-brokers/security-types/etps/education/faq/faq.htm).  The LSE ETC FAQ specifically mentions "ETF Securities" by name, and addresses questions such as how/where they are regulated, what happens to investments if "ETF Securities" were to go bankrupt, etc.

I hope this helps, but *please, do your own due diligence.*